# На моб. версии сайта перестал работать скролл вниз с главной странице

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, прокрутка, firefox, safari

Всем привет. На моем сайте в мобильной версии перестал работать скролл вниз(раньше нормально было). Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить уже вот как 3 дня ломаю голову не могу найти в чем проблема. вот ссылка на сайт: sofmetal.uz

Comment: у вас у `body` прописан `overflow: hidden`, который меняется на `auto`, если нажать в любое место, после чего скрол начинает работать.